# Having trouble removing a library that is linked and added with yarn

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hyperlink, yarnpkg

So my project is using [react native image picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker) and I'm switching to a different library in order to select multiple photos.

So I'm removing the image picker library by running first:
`react-native unlink react-native-image-picker` which gives a successful message and then I run
`yarn remove react-native-image-picker`.

They both seem to work.

Now when I run the simulator, I get this error message: 
`error: Build input file cannot be found: '../../../react-native-image-picker/ios/ImagePickerManager.m`

`error Failed to build iOS project. We ran xcodebuild command but it exited with error code 65`

I am using cocoapods. I have a feeling that's important. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: You gotta remove it from Pods.

Comment: @SanyamJain I don't see it in the podfile at all. Is there a specific way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. `react-native unlink react-native-image-picker`
2. `yarn remove react-native-image-picker`
3. `cd ios && rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock && pod install`

This should work.

Comment: So this answer worked yet I'm getting errors on Android. `Android resource linking failed`

Comment: had to remove it from the mainapplication.java file and androidmanifest but it works on android now! thx again!